# Ajax POST don't work after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My problem is lack of action after pressing the button. Under the button hook AJAX function. 
Please a hint where I have a bug // errors.

My code:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertCodesToDB(string name)
    {
        cl.InsertCodesToDB(name);
        fl.MoveCodeFileToAccept(name);

        string response = "Test";
        return Content(response, "application/json");  
    }
```

View / Button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success sendCodesToDB" value="Umieść kody w bazie" data-value="@item.Name"/>
```

View / Script:

```
<script>
$('.sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

    var name = $(this).data("value");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ActualCodes/InsertCodesToDB',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': 'name' }),
        success: function (response) {
                @(ViewBag.MessageOK) = response;
        },
        error: function () {
            onBegin;
        }
    });
});

function onBegin() {
        $('#files').hide();
        $('#insertFiles').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#lblSelectedProductName').text('Trwa umieszczanie kodów w bazie danych. Proszę czekać ...');
        $('#ttt').show();
}
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which error are you getting ? Change it to `JSON.stringify({ 'name': name}),` Remove quote.

Comment: is onBegin function is called or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in Ajax must be JavaScript. You cannot use C# code there (except to print some values). What is `@(ViewBag.MessageOK)` doing here:

```
success: function (response) {
    @(ViewBag.MessageOK) = response;
},
```

If you want to display the response in a message box, try something like:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#your_message_id").html(response);
},
```

Notes: aside from that, you have several errors in your code as others pointed out in the comments.

1- Remove the quotes from the `data` like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
```

2- Change the `error` to this:

```
error: function () {
   onBegin(); // You need "()" here
}
```

Or better this:

```
error: onBegin // You don't need "()" here
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used all of your tips and ajax started to work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not be adding the on ready function for jQuery. Try adding it before your click action and closing it before your onBegin() function, like so:

```
<script>
// open here
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

       var name = $(this).data("value");

       $.ajax({
           url: '/ActualCodes/InsertCodesToDB',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': 'name' }),
           success: function (response) {
                   @(ViewBag.MessageOK) = response;
           },
           error: function () {
               // function call missing "()"
               onBegin();
           }
       });
    });
// and close here
});

function onBegin() {
    $('#files').hide();
    $('#insertFiles').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#lblSelectedProductName').text('Trwa umieszczanie kodów w bazie danych. Proszę czekać ...');
    $('#ttt').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is only required if the script comes before the HTML (e.g. in the header). Otherwise, it is just a recommendation, not the solution to the OP's issue. In modern designs, it is always recommended to place your JavaScript at the end of the HTML, in which case `ready` is rarely required.

Comment: You are correct, but seeing as it is a common mistake, it might actually be the answer the author is looking for.

Comment: Agreed, which is why you're upvoted ;), but I just wanted to explain for OP and all future readers to learn the modern design and when `ready` is required.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are sending data inside the AJAX call in the wrong way.

Try it like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: name })
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's definitely an issue, but it is not the main issue. Somebody has already mentioned it in the comments and that's enough, because it is not an answer.